# How do I install imagemagick to php on linux homebrew?

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick

I'm trying to set up my linux environment to use PHP for my job. I'll spare you most of the details, but one extension I need is ImageMagick. I'm using Homebrew to help me install stuff. I'm using PHP 7.4. The commands I've run based on what I've read are as follows:

```
brew install php@7.4
brew install imagemagick
pecl install imagcik
```

However, when running the last command, I get this error, saying `pcre2.h` not found:
[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/56V2P.png)

I've done a lot of googling and haven't been able to find anything that helps with this specific issue. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Everything is currently done through homebrew, but if it helps my linux distro is OpenSUSE Tumbleweed. Thanks!

Comment: Please do not post images of error messages. Post the text.  You misspelled imagick as imagcik.  Not sure if that relates to your error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you did install `pcre2` (if you didn't, run the command below and try again).

```
$ brew install pcre2
```

If that does not work, the issue is probably that the file exists, but in the wrong spot. A quick Google search shows that creating a symlink can resolve this issue.

```
$ ln -s <path to package> /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/php@7.4/7.4.27/include/php/ext/pcre/pcre2.h
```

If you're unsure where the package is currently installed. You should be able to find it with this command.

```
$ brew info pcre2
```